# How to change all products titles in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, product, magento2.4, magento2.3.5, title

How to change all products titles using script or coding in Magento 2.
I need to change all the products title on product description page.

Answer (score 1):

> etc\di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product" 
type="Magepow\Product\Plugin\Model\Catalog\Product" /></config>
```

> Magepow\Product\Plugin\Model\Catalog\Product.php

```
namespace Magepow\Product\Plugin\Model\Catalog;
class Product extends \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product{
    public function getName(){
              return $this-_getData(self::NAME) . ' + Hello WO';
          }
    public function getSku(){
              return "Demo-Hello";
          }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change all products titles then you can use a preference or modify it  you can use a preference like below :
In your etc/di.xml add this:

```
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product" type="Vendor\Module\Model\Product" />
```

and in Vendor\Module\Model\Product.php, add below code :

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Model;

class Product extends \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product
{
    public function getName()
    {
         $changeNamebyPreference = $this->_getData('name') . ' MODIFIED BY PREFERENCE';
         return $changeNamebyPreference;
    }
}
```

`$this->_getData('name')` returns products default title.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Create app/code///etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product">
        <plugin name="change_catalog_product_title" type="<vendorName>\<moduleName>\Plugin\Catalog\Model\Product"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

Step 2: app/code/<moduleName>/Plugin/Catalog/Model/Product.php

```
<?php

namespace <vendorName>\<moduleName>\Plugin\Catalog\Model;

class Product
{
    public function afterGetName(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $subject, $result)
    {
        // $title = $subject->getAttributeText(''); // call any custom attr like this of current product
        $title = "hello";
        return $title." - ". $result . ' MODIFIED BY PREFERENCE';
    }
}
```

That's it - Happy Coding